# Locate string/integer not in list

Tags: ansible, jinja2

Im pulling a list of VLANs from our IPAM via an API and I want to be able to locate an unused "vlanId" that isnt in the list. I was expecting that I could use  with_items for the JSON content and then use the random function with an until loop and occasionally it will initially generate a number that doesnt exist in the list. Mostly it just gets stuck and doesnt generate a new random number when the one generated already exists.

Playbook:

```
  - uri:
      url: "#"
      validate_certs: no
      headers:
        token: "{{ token }}"
      method: GET
      force_basic_auth: yes
      return_content: yes
      register: ipam

  - set_fact:
      value: "{{ 4094 | random(start=1) }}"
    until: value not in item.vlanId
    with_items: "{{ ipam.json.data }}"
    retries: 4093

  - debug: msg="{{ value }}"
```

Relevant Output:

```
ok: [localhost] => (item={u'domainId': u'3', u'description': u'#', u'editDate': None, u'Customer ID': None, u'number': u'2241', u'vlanId': u'548', u'name': u'2241', u'Customer Name': None, u'custom_fields': None, u'Engineer': None}) => {
    "ansible_facts": {
        "value": "2727"
    },
    "ansible_facts_cacheable": false,
    "attempts": 1,
    "changed": false,
    "item": {
        "Customer ID": null,
        "Customer Name": null,
        "Engineer": null,
        "custom_fields": null,
        "description": "#",
        "domainId": "3",
        "editDate": null,
        "name": "2241",
        "number": "2241",
        "vlanId": "548"
    }
}
ok: [localhost] => (item={u'domainId': u'3', u'description': u'#', u'editDate': None, u'Customer ID': None, u'number': u'2242', u'vlanId': u'549', u'name': u'2242', u'Customer Name': None, u'custom_fields': None, u'Engineer': None}) => {
    "ansible_facts": {
        "value": "1955"
    },
    "ansible_facts_cacheable": false,
    "attempts": 1,
    "changed": false,
    "item": {
        "Customer ID": null,
        "Customer Name": null,
        "Engineer": null,
        "custom_fields": null,
        "description": "#",
        "domainId": "3",
        "editDate": null,
        "name": "2242",
        "number": "2242",
        "vlanId": "549"
    }
}
FAILED - RETRYING: set_fact (4000 retries left).Result was: {
    "ansible_facts": {
        "value": "50"
    },
    "ansible_facts_cacheable": false,
    "attempts": 1,
    "changed": false,
    "retries": 4001
}

FAILED - RETRYING: set_fact (3999 retries left).Result was: {
    "ansible_facts": {
        "value": "50"
    },
    "ansible_facts_cacheable": false,
    "attempts": 2,
    "changed": false,
    "retries": 4001
}

FAILED - RETRYING: set_fact (3998 retries left).Result was: {
    "ansible_facts": {
        "value": "50"
    },
    "ansible_facts_cacheable": false,
    "attempts": 3,
    "changed": false,
    "retries": 4001
```

Im currently using ansible 2.4.2.0

If this is something that cant/shouldnt be done in Ansible, any guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what you want:

```
- debug:
    msg: "{{ range(1, 4095) | difference(vlanIds) | random }}"
  vars:
    vlanIds: "{{ ipam.json.data | map(attribute='vlanId') | list }}"
```

Explanation:

1. `map(attribute=...` - create a list of vlan IDs,
2. `range` - generate a sequence from 1 to 4094,
3. `difference` - select all the elements from the above. that are not on the `vlanIds` list,
4. `random` - select a random element from the above.

---

<sup>For strings (as the title suggests) replace `range` with a list of possible strings.</sup>